# Build latest hCsound with cabal

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal, csound

I'm trying to build hCsound-0.4.2 on Debian-linux machine, it seems, that since 2012 (latest version) there were some changes in csound.h file, but I'm not sure.

When trying `cabal install hcsound` I get following

```
Configuring hCsound-0.4.2...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing (or bad) header file: csound.h
```

I have libcsound64-dev of version 1:6.02~dfsg-2, which installs `csound.h` into `/usr/include/csound/`, so I did following:

```
cabal unpack hcsound
cd hCsound-0.4.2
cabal configure --extra-include-dirs=/usr/include/csound
cabal build
```

In that case, configuring is done nicely, but I get errors on build stage:

```
Preprocessing library hCsound-0.4.2...
c2hs: Error limit of 20 errors has been reached.
src/Sound/Csound/Foreign.chs:1224: (column 14) [ERROR]  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `csoundSetControlChannelParams' in the header file.
src/Sound/Csound/Foreign.chs:1118: (column 11) [ERROR]  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `CsoundChannelListEntry' in the header file.
src/Sound/Csound/Foreign.chs:1113: (column 22) [ERROR]  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `CsoundChannelListEntry' in the header file.
src/Sound/Csound/Foreign.chs:1111: (column 23) [ERROR]  >>> Unknown identifier!
  Cannot find a definition for `CsoundChannelListEntry' in the header file.
...
```

Some of the mentioned function names are present in `/usr/include/csound/csound.h`, some are not. Is there a possibility that c2hs processes wrong header?

What can be done to find out possible reasons for incorrect (?) behaviour? Has someone experience of building hCsound recently?

My intention is to use the library go produce sound output from Haskell program, so if anyone suggests better solution, it would also be great. I already failed to install haskore-supercollider, I have haskore package, but did not managed to get if it can produce sound in real time.

Comment: Ah, I haven't tried to build hCsound recently.  Could you please upload your `csound.h` somewhere and post a link, and I'll debug it?

Comment: @JohnL here I pasted `csound.h` along with some info about its version: http://pastebin.com/vFu2YrGq